# Automatically skip in-video ads on YouTube

Tags: web-browser, youtube, ad-blocker

I'm searching for an extension or script that can automatically skip to the start of a video without having to listen to the video author trying to sell me a product. Lots of content creators have started putting ads directly into their videos, and I'm searching for a way to skip them automatically.

[Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQ0S7GA0LIo).

[image: a screenshot of a content creator's ad]

An entire minute wasted. That's what I usually use uBlock Origin in combination with a modified hosts-file for, but they are unable to detect content embedded into the video file itself.

What the add-on would have to do:

- Find out where the author is selling things
- Skip that part

For that to work, there needs to be user generated content. Users need to  mark the points in the video with ads in them. Afterwards, the database is updated and other users don't need to watch these ads, since they'd be cut out.

This system seems similar to the equivalent domains feature in LastPass, where one user makes amazon.de an equivalent domain to amazon.com and other users will see the appropriate link too.

Does an extension or script like that exist? I'm not looking for uBlock Origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I think this is what you are looking for.](https://github.com/ajayyy/SponsorBlock)

Extensions for Chrome and Firefox are linked in the readme file.

Here's a screenshot of the skipped advertisement on a JonTron video. The part that the mouse is currently hovering over has been skipped automatically.

[image: youtube screenshot]